¿Por qué me deja crear una Persona con solo los check y las comboBox?
soy estudiante apenas inicié POO en Windows Form C# y tengo que hacer un formulario con ciertas validaciones. Quiero al darle click a un botón se verifique si todas las TxtBox , ComboBox y CheckBoxs esten completadas. Pero estoy presentando el error de que se crea una Persona cuando solo tengo los check y comboBox llenos, pero no valida los txtBox. Tendrían alguna idea de en que estoy fallando?:
  private bool ValidarTxt()
   {

     TextBox[] textBoxes = {txtb_name, txtb_apellido, txtb_email, txtb_numdoc, txtb_telefono 
   };

   foreach (TextBox txb in textBoxes)
   {
    if (txb.Text =="")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Por favor, llena todos los campos.");
        return false;
     }
   }

  return true;
}

  private bool ValidarCbox()
  {
     ComboBox[] comboBox = { Combox_ciudadexp, Combox_lugarexp, Combox_Tipedoc };
       foreach (ComboBox cbox in comboBox)
       {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbox.Text) || cbox.SelectedIndex == -1)
       {
        MessageBox.Show("Por favor, llena todos los campos.");
        return false;
        }
   }

   return true;
}

 private void Btn_continuar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   if (ValidarTxt() && ValidarCbox() && (Chbox_autorizacion.Checked && 
    Chbox_tratamiento.Checked))
   {
    CrearPersona();
   }     
   else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Falta información por llenar");
    }
 }


No aprecio error en el código, que pasa si cambias txb.Text =="" por string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txb.Text)  ?

Hola, gracias por tu sugerencia pero nada ha cambiado. Decidí quitar la validación de los Combo Box, y probar solamente con los check y la validación del txtBox. Pero por alguna razón no está sirvinedo ValidacionTxt, solamete toma los check

He copiado tu código tal como lo tienes pero funciona correctamente. Es probable que el textbox tenga un espacio en blanco ya que de ser asi, permite continuar.
Revisando tu manera de validar los textbox te recomendaria que valides los espacios en blanco, eso funciona en muchas ocasiones o bien que puedas validar un minimo de carácteres, ejemplo:
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txb.Text) || txb.Text.Length >= 3)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Por favor, llena todos los campos.");
    return false;
}

